# Notation and definition on book Presentations of Groups

Tags: notation, free-groups, group-presentation

On the 33th page of the book [Presentations of Groups](http://books.google.lu/books?id=RYeIcopMH-IC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), when talking about the Nielsen's Method to prove Nielsen–Schreier theorem, the authors consider $F$ as any free group, $H$ as any subgroup of $F$, and $\ll$ as an order on $F$. Then, they write exactly this:

> Given $w \in H$, define
>
> $$H(w) := < \{h \in H | h^{\pm} \ll w^{\pm} \} >,$$
>
> and then put
>
> $$A := \{a \in H | a \not\in H(a) \},$$
>
> so that A consists of just those $a \in H$ that cannot be written as words in smaller elements of $H$. Now let $B$ be a subset of $A$ obtained by throwing away exactly one of each inverse pair of elements of $A$, so that $A = B \cup B^{-1}$.

Thus, my questions are:

1. Does $h^{\pm} \ll w^{\pm}$ mean $(h \ll w$ and $h^{-1} \ll w^{-1})$?
2. What does "inverse pair of elements" mean? (If it was simply the inverse, then why to say "exactly one" since inverse is unique?).

Comment: Maybe: of the pair $\langle a , a^{-1} \rangle$ throw away one of $a$ and $a^{-1}$ and retain the other.

Comment: See page 1: $X^{\pm} = \{ x, x^{-1} \mid x \in X \}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I've already seen it, but that is a notation for sets (it is very clear, in fact). The one in the question is for elements.

Comment: For elements it is defined at page 31.